# pass array to includes() javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to find out if a string includes multiple strings stored in array with `.includes()`

So I've tried

```
let string = 'hello james';

console.log(string.includes(['hello', 'james']));
```

but it is being returned as `false`.. when I know the string includes 'hello' or 'james' is this even possible?? how can I tell if a string contains either the word 'hello' or 'james'

So in pseudo code this would look like `string.includes('hello' || 'james');`

Comment: `hello` and `james` should both be in the string  to be true?

Comment: @Eddie more like or so in pseudo code `string.includes('hello' || 'james');`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes), `includes` first parameter is a string and not an array.

You can do:

If you want to check if each and every string in the array is present on the string, you can use `every` and `includes` combo

```js
let string = 'hello james';
let toCheck = ['hello', 'james'];

let result = toCheck.every(o => string.includes(o));

console.log(result);
```

You can use `some` instead of `every` if you want to check at least one entry in the array is present on the string.

```js
let string = 'hello james';
let toCheck = ['hello', 'james1'];

let result = toCheck.some(o => string.includes(o));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Beat me to it :|

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes#Syntax), the `str.includes` takes a `string` as the first parameter.

So when you pass an array instead, it converts the array of strings to a single string, and uses that string as the first parameter of the includes function.

Just to demonstrate this point,

```
let string = "hello,james";
var array = ["hello", "james"]

console.log(string.includes(array)); // returns true, as array would be converted to "hello,james"
```