# How to filter data if it includes item in array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to .filter() an array to remove items from my data.map(), but I don't want to call filter() multiple times. How can I pass an array into .includes()?

this works, but uses multiple .filter()

```
const items = ['apple','pear','peach','pineapple'] 
        
return (
  <>
    {items
      .filter(item => !item.includes('r'))
      .filter(item => !item.includes('c'))
      .filter(item => !item.includes('i'))
      .map(item =>
         {item}
     )}
  </>
)
// returns 'apple'
```

I tried this but it's not right

```
const items = ['apple','pear','peach','pineapple'] 
const toBeRemoved = ['r','c','i'];
            
    return (
      <>
        {items
          .filter(item => !item.includes(toBeRemoved))
          .map(item =>
             {item}
         )}
      </>
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter` and [Array.prototype.some()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) together to achieve this

```js
const items = ["apple", "pear", "peach", "pineapple"];
const toBeRemoved = ["r", "c", "i"];

return (
    <>
      {items
        .filter((item) => !toBeRemoved.some((letter) => item.includes(letter)))
        .map((item) => (
          <div>{item}</div>
        ))}
    </>
);
```

Comment: sweet, easy enough, thank you

Answer (score 1):

my answer was simple, [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55331172/pass-array-to-includes-javascript) :

.filter(item => !toBeRemoved.some(i => item.includes(i)))

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you just have the ordering of `includes` backward. It's a property of arrays, so you have to start with the list of things, and ask what it might include. You have it the wrong way around.

Then also your map function is returning undefined, so you wouldn't get any results anyway. Maybe you confused it for the curly brackets in JSX that let you insert variables? But in this case they're acting as a function body. This might work?

```
    const items = ['apple','pear','peach','pineapple'] 
    const toBeRemoved = ['r','c','i'];
            
    return (
      <ul>
        {items
          .filter(item => !toBeRemoved.includes(item))
          .map(item => (
            <li>item</li>
          ))
        }
      </ul>
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const items = ['apple','pear','peach','pineapple'] 
const toBeRemoved = ['r','c','i'];
            
return (
  <ul>
    {items
      .filter(item => toBeRemoved.every(word => !item.includes(word)))
      .map(item => <li>{item}</li>)
    }
  </ul>
)
```

`array.every()` is equivalent to `!array.some()`

- .some(callback): loops each items of array with callback. If at least one callback returns truthy, some() returns `true`.
- .every(callback): If at least one callback returns falsy, every() returns `false`.

Answer (score 0):

As includes method take only single string value and returns true if found.
But in filter function we can attach multiple conditions.
So, this can help you.

```js
const items = ['apple','pear','peach','pineapple'] 
const toBeRemoved = ['r','c','i'];
            
console.log(items.filter(item => !item.includes("r") && !item.includes("c") && !item.includes("i")));
```